# How to multiply a large number in sql with out getting a "overflow error " error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I know this maybe a silly question; but how do I multiply large numbers in SQL Server without getting this error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

I need to take a column that contains a list of 6 digit client numbers.

E.g. 123456, 123457 and make it 1234560000000, 1234570000000 & etc.

This is what I tried doing.

```
update account set sClientIdNo =  sClientIdNo * 100000000
```

But I end up with the overflow error.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**  i forgot to mention that the column which contained the client numbers had a **varchar** data type.

Comment: Try BIGINT, see if that is big enough for you.

Comment: Change the column type to `bigint`.

Comment: Hi thanks.    I tried that but it did not work. .

Comment: Hi I created a new colum and made that column BIGINT , i then moved all info to the new column and ran my query. IT worked perfect.

Comment: You can also try `decimal(38,0)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what worked for me.

```
UPDATE account SET sClientIdNo = CONVERT(bigint, sClientIdNo  ) * 100000000
```

[@shA.t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4519059/sha-t) Provided the clue i needed by declaring @a a numeric.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to use `numeric` type like this:

```
DECLARE @a numeric(14, 0) = 123456
SELECT  @a * 100000000
```

Note that I use `14` for your requirement you can use bigger values for precision.